# Should I speak to a convert who has e.g. returned to using Facebook?

Tags: behavior

I know someone who is a convert alhamduliah, he travelled abroad to gain knowledge a year after converting, and alhamduliah he removed all those that were not good for him in his deen.

But now 3 years later, his going back on everything that he has been against.  For example, Facebook: he never liked it for the fact that it allowed gender interaction and he is now on Facebook and adding all his old friends that are non-Muslim, and also sin a lot astaghfirallah.  May Allah guide them to Islam.

He also added a few girls including a girl he had strong desires for and was in a past relationship with before converting, they are now speaking via Facebook; I don't know what's being said but I'm afraid this brother is going off track. I don't want to judge because he may be giving dawah, allowing his old friends to understand, but allahu aalam.

I mean my question is what do I do?  Should I speak to this brother?

Could it mean that he is going off track because of what he is doing and this girl situation?

Answer (score 1):

The Deen (Religion) is good advice. (taken from the 40 hadeeth).

So if you know this person, before you start posting about him, I think you should first speak to him to ascertain the real situation and give him good advice.

You cannot force anyone nor should you convince them by telling false stories. Rather, advice the person with the truth.

You cannot come to conclusions. So please be safe and do not pass judgement on your friend.

If he truly turns away from Islam, then it is his seeking.

Wallaahu a'alam.

Comment: +1 for The Deen (Religion) is good advice. It is the duty of the brother to given sincere advice if the other brother deviates from the path